# how to set company name should start with character javascript validation rule? it can contain Numbers and special characters followed by character

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, knockout-validation

i want to set validation rule for company names which should start with character and it can contain numbers and special characters..

For example:

1. 360 Angel - should not be allowed
2. Angel 360 - Allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript regular expressions should help

Documentation:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev3.shtml

Simple example:

```
var str = "360 Angel";
/^[a-zA-Z].*/.test(str); // return false
```